# XSLT insert sibling if it doesn't exist - Not being rerunnable for some reason

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to add a sibling to an element only if it doesn't exist.

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<domain xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml/1.0/xacml.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/providers/passwordvalidator http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/providers/passwordvalidator/1.0/passwordvalidator.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/domain.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/security.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls/1.0/wls.xsd">
  <security-configuration>
    <realm>
      <sec:authentication-provider xsi:type="wls:default-authenticatorType">
        <wls:use-retrieved-user-name-as-principal>true</wls:use-retrieved-user-name-as-principal>
      </sec:authentication-provider>
      <sec:authentication-provider xsi:type="wls:default-identity-asserterType">
        <sec:active-type>AuthenticatedUser</sec:active-type>
      </sec:authentication-provider>
    </realm>
  </security-configuration>
</domain>
```

The desired output should be:

```
<domain xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml/1.0/xacml.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/providers/passwordvalidator http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/providers/passwordvalidator/1.0/passwordvalidator.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/domain.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/security.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls/1.0/wls.xsd">
  <security-configuration>
    <realm>
      <sec:authentication-provider xsi:type="wls:default-authenticatorType">
        <wls:use-retrieved-user-name-as-principal>true</wls:use-retrieved-user-name-as-principal>
      </sec:authentication-provider>
      <sec:authentication-provider xsi:type="wls:default-identity-asserterType">
        <sec:active-type>AuthenticatedUser</sec:active-type>
      </sec:authentication-provider>
   <!-- Just adding this element -->    
      <sec:authentication-provider xmlns:ext="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/extension" xsi:type="ext:session-authenticatorType">
        <sec:name>SessionAuthenticator</sec:name>
        <sec:control-flag>SUFFICIENT</sec:control-flag>
      </sec:authentication-provider>

    </realm>
  </security-configuration>
</domain>
```

This transformation needs to be rerunnable, so I need to only add the new element if it doesn't exist.

Here's the XLST I'm trying to use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:bi="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:sec="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security"              
                xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8' indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>  
<!-- match the existing child of realm -->
<xsl:template match="bi:realm/sec:authentication-provider[@xsi:type='wls:default-identity-asserterType']">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>

  <!-- If the element doesn't exist already add it as a sibling -->
  <xsl:if test="not(bi:realm/sec:authentication-provider[@xsi:type='ext:session-authenticatorType'])">    
    <sec:authentication-provider xmlns:ext="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/extension" xsi:type="ext:session-authenticatorType">
      <sec:name>SessionAuthenticator</sec:name>
      <sec:control-flag>SUFFICIENT</sec:control-flag>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

When running this transform the desired element gets added. However the problem is that this isn't rerunnable. The check for the existence of the new element gets ignored every time I run this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template matches a `sec:authentication-provider` element:

```
match="bi:realm/sec:authentication-provider[...]"
```

So, within the template, the context node is the matched `sec:authentication-provider` element. Therefore, when you perform your test, you need to proceed from that context. Your current test

```
test="not(bi:realm/sec:authentication-provider[@xsi:type='ext:session-authenticatorType'])"
```

would only work if the context node were the parent of `bi:realm`, namely `bi:security-configuration`. Since the context node is a `sec:authentication-provider` element, and you want to test for a sibling, your test should be as follows:

```
test="not(../sec:authentication-provider[@xsi:type='ext:session-authenticatorType'])"
```

In practice, if I'm not mistaken, the sibling you're testing for would always come *after* the matched element. So you could use `following-sibling::` instead of `../`.

Comment: You're right. Do you know by any chance why if I remove the namespace id xmlns:bi I can't do a match for match="bi:realm/sec:authentication-provider[...]"? It seems that match="realm/sec:authentication-provider[...]" isn't working. However realm is not defined with a specific namespace except the default one inherited from <domain>.

Comment: @keftes, that's right: `<realm>` inherits the default namespace from `<domain>`, namely the namespace whose URI is `http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain`. So if you want the match pattern to match `realm`, you must specify that namespace in the match pattern (or explicitly make your match pattern namespace-insensitive). The way you specify that namespace in your match pattern is by declaring a prefix for it (`xmlns:bi="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain"`) in your XSLT and then using the `bi` prefix in your match pattern.